# 8086 Assembly - Constants and reading chars from array

Tags: assembly, constants, x86-16

I have to write an 8086 assembly program that plays music notes.

I declared notes as constants, melody is stored in memory, program reads note after note, 'X' means that  melody has ended. My problem is that I have no idea how change ASCII code to value of constant. For example when program reads character 'C' it should write its constant value (9107) to AX.

Here is my code:

```
dosIntr         equ     21h
retToDos        equ     4ch
noError         equ     0h
;octave
C               =9107 ;1193000/131
D               =8115 ;1193000/147
E               =7230 ;1193000/165
F               =6817 ;1193000/175
G               =6087 ;1193000/196
A               =5423 ;1193000/220
B               =4830 ;1193000/247
W               =1 ;pause 

Progr           segment
                assume  cs:Progr, ds:data, ss:stack
start:          mov     ax,data
                mov     ds,ax
                mov     ax,stack
                mov     ss,ax
                mov     sp,offset stack

                mov     si,0 ;index

play:   ;read char from array   
                mov     bl,notes[si] ;ascii code of note
                cmp     bl,'X' ;check if end
                je      soundEnd

        ;changing ascii to constant
                mov     ax,bx ;copies only ascii code           

        ;8253 send note         
                out     42h,al
                mov     al,ah
                out     42h,al

        ;8255 sound on
                in      al,61h
                or      al,00000011b
                out     61h,al

        ;int15 timer
                xor     dx,dx ;dx = 0
                mov     cx,8 ;half note
                mov     ah,86h
                int     15h

        ;8255 sound off
                in      al,61h
                and     al,11111100b
                out     61h,al

                inc     si ;inc index
                jmp     play


soundEnd:       mov     ah,retToDos
                mov     al,noError
                int     dosIntr
Progr           ends

data            segment
    notes db 'CWDWEWFWGWAWBWX' 
data            ends


stack          segment
                dw    100h dup(0)
top          Label word
stack          ends


end start
```

Comment: My recommendation would be to create an array of 7 elements (A-G both included) and set in the notes position (A, B, etc...) the value. Handle W apart (check with conditionals), check with conditional too that input are note letter and index the array for getting the value.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. It turned out very easy.